# How to get Cookies using HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

Hello I am using HttpClient to get Cookies but I am unable find any cookies. My Code is given below:

```
public class LoginTab {

    private Cookie[] cookies;
    HttpClient httpClient;
    HttpState httpState;
    HashMap postData;

    public LoginTab() {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpState = new HttpState();
        httpClient.getHttpConnectionManager().
                getParams().setConnectionTimeout(300000);
        httpClient.setState(httpState);
        // RFC 2101 cookie management spec is used per default
        // to parse, validate, format & match cookies
        httpClient.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);
        postData= new HashMap();
    }

    public String getMethod(String url) {
        GetMethod getMethod = new GetMethod(url);
          String pageSoure="";
        try{
        httpClient.executeMethod(getMethod);
         pageSoure=getMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
        extractUsefulPostData(pageSoure, postData);
        getMethod.releaseConnection();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pageSoure;
    }
    public static void main(String[]arg)
    {
        LoginTab loginTab= new LoginTab();
        System.out.println(loginTab.getMethod("http://tab.com.au/"));
        Cookie [] cookies=loginTab.httpState.getCookies();
        System.out.println(cookies.length);
        for(int i=0;i<cookies.length;i++)
            System.out.println(cookies[i]);
    }
}
```

Please tell me I've made a mistake.
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you not provide any more details? what errors are you being given?

Comment: There is no error I want to count how  many cookies are there when I am using Mozile Live Http Headers there are cookies
Cookie: Language=Language_LocaleID=3081; Account=Account_DisplayBalance=1; __utma=167555387.2008132460.1269847689.1269937122.1269946500.6; __utmz=167555387.1269847689.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); _dmnid=920336_1269934756044

Comment: Thanks for your responce thecosman..

Comment: oh, I notice you add the JAVA tag, was about to ask what language. Are you just trying to make your own web browser in java... presumably just for giggle and poops. (I prefer to phrase the differently, but I be PC)

Comment: This might help you: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/GetCookievalueandsetcookievalue.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with all the CookiePolicy available and also setting "user-agent" stuff without success.
From what i see with java - verbose there's a trapped exception in getCookie() method that raises:

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.DateParseException
```

Probably cookie received from site (i can see it with Cookie Editor on firefox) has something not good for httpclient; have a look at [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/httpclient-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg00703.html) thread for the same problem.
From what i see, you need to enable logging and check what httpclient does on cookie parsing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Still there is no cookies